# How to create a new string which is n copies of a given string in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I create a new string which is n copies of a given string in ruby?
I tried these but none of them worked -

```
n = 5
string = "This is a string"
my_string = ""
my_string =  n.times do
  my_string << string
end

puts my_string
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array with `n` `string` elements, and then join each of them:

```
Array.new(n, string).join
# "This is a stringThis is a stringThis is a stringThis is a stringThis is a string"
```

You can also use the `*` method which *returns a new String containing integer copies of self*:

```
string * n
# "This is a stringThis is a stringThis is a stringThis is a stringThis is a string"
```

Comment: The latter is syntactically cleaner, the former is nice if you want to add a separator rather than just banging the substrings together: `Array.new(2, string).join(' ') # => "This is a string This is a string"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-2A) operator:

```
n = 5
string = "This is a string"
my_string = string * n
```

```
This is a stringThis is a stringThis is a stringThis is a stringThis is a string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-2A) method. For example:

```
str = "This is a string.\n"
str * 5
#=> "This is a string.\nThis is a string.\nThis is a string.\nThis is a string.\nThis is a string.\n"
```

Similarly, `puts str * 5` will return nil, but print the output with newlines to standard output. For example:

> ```
> This is a string.
> This is a string.
> This is a string.
> This is a string.
> This is a string.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for. But you can use the string * integer method.

```
n = 5
string = "This is a string"
my_string = string * n

puts my_string
```

Comment: my_string = n * string    What's wrong with this?

Comment: @RaviKumar The order matters.  If the integer is on the left, Ruby expects to the right side to be number and will do multiplication.  If the string is on the left, Ruby expects the right side to be a number and will do the string duplication and concatenation.